# Prove the given inequality related to log-sum inequality.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, inequality, logarithms, expected-value

Let $$ X_{1}, \cdots, X_{n}, X_{n+1}$$ be independent and identically distributed random variables such that $$ P(m \leq X_{1} \leq M) = 1, ~ \infty > M \geq m > 0$$
for given constants $m$ and $M$. Then, I want to show the following inequality
$$
E \left \{ \log \left ( \frac{c + \sum_{i=1}^{n+1} X_{i}}{c + \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}}\right ) \right \}  = E \left \{ \log \left ( 1 + \frac{X_{n+1}}{c + \sum_{i=1}^{n} X_{i}}\right ) \right \} \geq \log \left ( 1 + \frac{1}{n+1} \right ), ~ {}^{\forall} n \geq 1,
$$
where $c$ is a constant satisfying $0 < c \leq E(X_{1})$.

I found that the LHS of the above inequality is related to the log-sum inequality. However, it is hard to find the literature about the lower bound of that term.

I numerically check that the above inequality holds.

Thanks for reading this post.

Comment: I haven't checked this myself, but I would try using Jensens inequality since all that remains is computing the expected value without dealing with the logarithm.

Comment: Thank you for comment! In my knowledge, applying the Jensen's inequality (i.e., exchanging the expectation and logarithm) gives an upper bound of the given inequality, not the required lower bound. Could you explain more details about what you meant?

Comment: Any information about the problem, e.g., source, why do you think it might be true?